# How to limit the number of iterations through the List 

Tags: java, arraylist, caldav

How I can limit the result of an iterator over my List?

```
try {
    ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput> results = new ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput>();

    List<?> eventsToday = (List<?>) filter.filter(calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT));
    CalanderQueryOutput caldavOutput = new CalanderQueryOutput();

    for (Iterator<?> i = eventsToday.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    }
    results.add(caldavOutput);
}
```

I want list only maximum ten results

Comment: what do you mean by limit, go up to certain number and break loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop , use a counter and check it like this:

```
if(counter < 10) results.add(caldavOutput);
.....
......
counter++;
```

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar Chandhrasekaran how about you accept his answer then

Answer (score 1):

You can add a counter and `break;` the loop when the counter reaches a certain value.

Before the loop:

```
int counter = 1;
```

in the loop:

```
if(counter >= 10)
   break;

/* loop code */

counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
...
for (Object event : eventsToday.subList(0, Math.min(9, eventsToday.size() - 1))) {
    // do something with "event"
}
...
```